# How to plot two variables on two different y-axes in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, axis

I try to build a graphy with one x-axis and two y-axes, with all axes comming from a dataframe (similar to the graphs [here](https://tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations)). Here are my example data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'year': [2000, 2001, 2002], 
                        'deaths': [327, 456, 509], 
                        'cheese': [13.5, 13.7, 13.8]})
```

---

I only found questions covering [multiple lines based on a categorical variable (what I don't need)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071096/how-to-plot-multiple-lines-in-one-figure-in-pandas-python-based-on-data-from-mul) or [more than two axis with an answer I, as a beginner, don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640243/pandas-plot-multiple-y-axes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `matplotlib.pyplot` module creates a figure and axes object (see `help(plt.subplots)` for details) that can be used to create a plot as requested:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Impot the relevant module

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # Create the figure and axes object

# Plot the first x and y axes:
df.plot(x = 'year', y = 'deaths', ax = ax) 
# Plot the second x and y axes. By secondary_y = True a second y-axis is requested:
# (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html for details)
df.plot(x = 'year', y = 'cheese', ax = ax, secondary_y = True)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I got an `AttributeError: Unknown property secondary_y`. Which version of matplotlib you are using?

Comment: @tillKadabra: ´print(matplotlib.__version__)´ gave 3.1.1